# Add independent labels to ggplot (weighted) violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to add a set of extra explanatory labels to each factor in a ggplot weighted violin plot. In the dummy example below I would like the field 'extra' in the dataframe'LBLS' to plot the label at y-value 2, which is just below each respective violin.  This attempt did not work as there is something I'm not understanding about the way ggplot works (yet).

```
require(ggplot2)
LBLS <- data.frame(c("Species A", "Species B","Species C"))
names(LBLS) <- "Extra"

ggplot(data = iris, aes_string(x = names(iris)[5], y = names(iris)[2], fill = names(iris)[5] ), weight = names(iris)[4]) +             # data and weight
  geom_violin(show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Weighted violin plots") +
  geom_label(x = names(iris)[5], y = 2,  label = LBLS$Extra)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntax improvements that may make things clearer.  But the main issue is that if you want "Species A" to be a label over "setosa", you need to associate those two values as going hand-in-hand.  There are a couple of ways to do that.  Here's one that joins `lbls` data frame with `iris`, and then plots:

```r
lbls <- tibble(Extra = c("Species A", "Species B", "Species C"),
               Species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))

iris %>% 
  left_join(lbls, by = "Species") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, weight = Petal.Width)) +           
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Extra), y = 2) +
  labs(title = "Weighted violin plots")
```

[image]

Here's another approach, which avoids a join. Make a map of "Species [X]" values to `iris$Species` values, and then add a column to `iris` using that map:

```r
lbls2 <- list(setosa = "Species A", 
              versicolor = "Species B", 
              virginica = "Species C")

iris %>% 
  mutate(extra = lbls2[Species]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, weight = Petal.Width)) +           
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(label = extra), y = 2) +
  labs(title = "Weighted violin plots")
```

Comment: Thanks - like your second solution best -  also did not realize you could chain the dplr with the ggplot so will add that to my ggplot box of tricks that I'm just starting to learn